# Marlett Font: Can I load it and use it in WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

**What functions do I use to load the [Marlett](http://www.reactos.org/wiki/Marlett_Characters) font in Native WinAPI(if its possible)?**

I am attempting to create my own transparent checkbox in Native WinAPI. I am at the stage where I need to draw the **checkbox tick** therefore it would be cool if I could just load the Marlett font then TextOut() - ie print - the checkbox tick.

Maybe I need to obtain a copy of the Marlett font as a file then I load it in at runtime, or is it on all Windows OS's from 2k upwards?

http://www.siao2.com/2006/01/26/517738.aspx

Answer (score 5):

This is answered trivially by consulting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marlett):

> Marlett is a TrueType font that has been used in Microsoft Windows since Windows 95.

Hence you can just load the font using the conventional [`CreateFont`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`CreateFontIndirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), if you prefer.

Comment: @konrad_rudolph do I use Create_font, pretty sure that makes a bitmap font not vector. What WinAPI function/method can you suggest I use to load then use the font.

Comment: @Jake There is no difference since you specify a fixed size and style anyway. All the details are handled by the font API (in particular antialiasing / ClearType). `CreateFont` or `CreateFontIndirect ` is the way to go.

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to explain why a technically accurate answer is downvoted?

Comment: Bonus tip:  When creating the font, be sure to specify `SYMBOL_CHARSET`.  If you use `0` or `ANSI_CHARSET`, then font fallback sometimes kicks in and you get regular text instead of the symbols you're trying to render.